# GPU-enabled CNTK 2.0 for Python appears to hang with 100% CPU thread workload in Anaconda 3 4.4.0, Windows 10 Pro 64bit

Tags: python, installation, gpu, anaconda, cntk

Is there a known issue that prevents the GPU-enabled version of CNTK 2.0 from running in Anaconda 3 4.4.0 64bit, Windows 10 Pro 64bit?

I have installed Anaconda 4.4.0, created an environment with Python 3.6.1 and installed CNTK using the precompiled CNTK GPU image for Python 3.6, according to the instructions found under "First time CNTK installation", here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cognitive-toolkit/Setup-Windows-Python

The quick installation test works fine:

```
python -c "import cntk; print(cntk.__version__)"
```

However, when I invoke a CNTK function, for example:

```
import cntk
cntk.minus([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]).eval()
```

one thread of the CPU takes 100% workload and the program doesn't produce any output. It freezes until I press "<"CTRL>+"<"BREAK>, at which point it is terminated and the respective CPU thread workload falls back to 0%.

Similarly, in the following example, the program hangs when it executes the last line:

```
import numpy as np
x = cntk.input_variable(2)
y = cntk.input_variable(2)
x0 = np.asarray([[2., 1.]], dtype=np.float32)
y0 = np.asarray([[4., 6.]], dtype=np.float32)
cntk.squared_error(x, y).eval({x:x0, y:y0})
```

The GPU load is 0% at all times, while attempting to run the examples.

When I replace the GPU-enabled version of CNTK with the CPU-only version, in the same anaconda environment, the examples work as expected.

Comment: FWIW, the example works correctly on Anaconda3-4.3.1 with Python 3.6. I suggest opening this as an issue on the CNTK GitHub.

Comment: My comment above should read "with Python 3.5"

Comment: Thank you @IanA. I replicated your setup and I had exactly the same issue. 

I realised that whatever causes the problem probably relates to the NVIDIA drivers. 

I reinstalled the drivers and still had the issue. Then, I thought of disabling SLI, just in case... which made the difference. 

Nowhere in the installation of CNTK is this mentioned. It likely relates to the CUDA libraries.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was resolved by deactivating SLI from the NVIDIA Control Panel.